# Is there a way to iterate through a lua table continuously?

Tags: lua

I am developing a turn-based game and I have a player table of the following structure

```lua
players = {
    ["p1"] = Player(),
    ["p2"] = Player(),
    ...
    ["pn"] = Player()
}
```

What I wanted to do is iterate through each players in the table (after each player played his round) and get back to the first index ("p1" in this case)

So it should do the following stuff when I run the code

```lua
function shift()
    -- do stuff to shift the player's turn
    print(player.name)
end

shift() -- "p1"
shift() -- "p2"
...
shift() -- "pn"
shift() -- "p1"
-- and so on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```lua
local index
function shift()
   if not index then index = next(players) end
   print(players[index].name)
   index = next(players, next)
end
```

That should do what you want, if I understood the question correctly ;)

---

EDIT:

As Egor Skriptunoff pointed out in his comment, you can also have the function return the key and use `and` instead of an `if`:

```lua
local index
function shift()
   index = next(players,index)
   return index or next(players)
end
```

Comment: second argument for `next` is key, so must be `index = next(players, index)`

Comment: `local index; function shift() index = next(players, index) or next(players); return index; end`

Answer (score -1):

Your loop should be something along the lines of:

```
for k, player in pairs(players) do
     player:Player()
end
```

If you want to recall the the first players function then just follow this with:

```
players[1]:Player()
```

Hope this helped!

Edit: To make it endless, just put it in a 'repeat until loop' so it would look something like:

```
repeat
    <for loop across all players>
until <condition>
```

Comment: I m already using a loop like that to make my player list. I have just given the structure of it. Also I want to access each player object until the end of the list, then come back to first element and continue the process continuesly. I think I have told that thing.clearly in my question

Comment: You have not mentioned 'Endlessly' in your question. Please make it clear over there.

Comment: i think the title says something similar to that ;)